# probleme of connection to Database Oracle 11G () withe Eclipse :

Tags: java

```java
package oracleDBconnexion;

import java.sql.*;
public class jdbcConnexion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:iliassalilou","system","system");
           Statement st =con.createStatement();
           String  sql="select from DEPT *";
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
           while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+ rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getInt(3)+" "+rs.getString(4)+" "+rs.getString(5));  
           }
           con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

}
```

in console:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. The `*` wildcard should be in the select list:

```
String sql = "select * from DEPT";
// Here -------------^
```